# airbrake:heroku:add_deploy_notification with multiple apps

Tags: deployment, heroku, airbrake

Attempting to [set up deploy notifications to Airbrake on Heroku deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/airbrake#set-up-deploy-notification) with `rake airbrake:heroku:add_deploy_notification` when you have multiple Heroku apps (i.e. git remotes) will yield:

```
 !    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
 !    Specify app with --app APP.
```

<s>It appears [Airbrake are aware of this](http://help.airbrake.io/discussions/hoptoad-notifier-patches-and-discussion/72-rake-task-for-heroku-deploy-hook-with-multiple-apps) but no *real* solution is offered.</s>

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A fix has now been pushed for this](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/commit/f616190c318ddf36c011f51e60f431528d9d601c).

You can set the environment variable `HEROKU_APP` to the name of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to running `rake airbrake:heroku:add_deploy_notification` you can [set a default Heroku remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting-from-scratch) by setting a `git config heroku.remote` to the desired branch.

So for example, to set up apps whose Heroku remotes are `staging` and `production`, you can:

```
$ git config heroku.remote staging
$ rake airbrake:heroku:add_deploy_notification

$ git config heroku.remote production
$ rake airbrake:heroku:add_deploy_notification

$ git config --unset heroku.remote
```